# Sonicwall: Allow WAN access to device on separate interface

Tags: firewall, nat, sonicwall

I've inherited a Sonicwall TZ-210 (SonicOS Enhanced 5.5.20-3o) firewall running a multiple interface config:

1st Interface: Running LAN (data network)
2nd Interface: Running PBX network (voice network)

I've disabled some NAT settings for the PBX server, and now the server (on X5) cannot communicate with the internet, nor is it reachable from X1. I've tried re-enabling the NAT policies and restarting the server, however there is still no luck.

Additionally, there is no status for the voice network (X5) as indicated in the screenshot below.

[image: Sonicwall Interface setup, why is there no status for X5?]

Question: How can I allow internet and access from X1 (WAN) to all of X5 interface or just the PBX server running on X5?

Here are the NAT policies:
[image]

..and here are the Routing policies:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Noah, it's hard to give you a specific answer without seeing your configuration.  If you could post some more details, we could probably help you.  You are obviously missing NAT  or FW policies to allow the traffic you want.  but without seeing your configuration or topology, it's difficult to say what they should be.

Comment: Also, are you running SonicOS Enhanced or standard?  This will help clarify where settings are in your configuration

Comment: @Ron and Mike, thanks for getting back to me! I've updated the question with some screenshots that may help. The TZ-210 is running SonicOS Enhanced. I've also noticed that there is no interface status for X5 as outlined in the 1st screenshot, is this normal? The NAT policies screenshot (not sure if this helps), shows the active NAT policies. I've disabled and removed policies for the PBX server in X5. So now, how do I enable the policies of forwarding to the server in X5?

Comment: If x5 is showing 'No Link' then I'd look into resolving that first.  Especially if there is a connection present.  The NAT policy is not terribly difficult if you have the Address Object setup for your server and Service objects configured for the ports needed.  Verify the connection on x5, the Server is in the Address Objects List and the services are available first.  Once that is done we can work on the policies.

Comment: Just posted an answer with a quick and dirty on creating the NAT rule.  Also, word of advice from an ongoing support case:  Don't upgrade to Sonic OS 5.9 if you have multiple IPs on a single NIC that will hit more than one interface, ie. a NIC with a 10.20.70.x and 10.20.71.y IP configured.  The 5.9 and newer firmware does not support this configuration.

Comment: @MikeNaylor your a life saver! Thanks for this! What would the best way to go about resolving/troubleshooting the X5 interface issue? Thanks for the heads up about the 5.9 upgrade, that was next on my list of to-dos.

Comment: @MikeNaylor, the cable seems to be fine, I'll replace it tomorrow to rule out any issues - the IP phones still work and receive IP addresses from the SW, additionally, they can connect with the PBX server. I just restarted the sonicwall and same issue on X5.. Played around with the link speeds, still no go. There is no 'Shutdown Port' on the advance tab. Any ideas? Its odd because i'm also seeing traffic on X5.

Comment: @MikeNaylor I can also see devices and get an IP when connected to an X5 switch. Why isn't Sonicwall properly recognizing the interface?

Comment: @MikeNaylor I'm not sure if address objects and setting NAT policies is the way to go (or maybe it is). The server in X5 can't see out of the x5 (voice) network. Thus would this be a routing issue? I'm trying to get the server to access the internet, thus allowing me to access the server from X1 and allowing the server to fetch updates and send email notifications.

Comment: can hosts on other interfaces see the server on x5?

Comment: @MikeNaylor No they cannot. Nor can I when connected via SSLVPN and routed to the x5 network. I can't ping any hosts.

Comment: @MikeNaylor, alright it looks like there was an issue with the cable afterall. Though I still can't access the server in X5 from X1. I checked the rules and there is a rule allowing everything (all set as any) form Voice to LAN, and vice-versa LAN to Voice. Is there a way to only make the server (in X5) accessible through X1?

Comment: updated answer to remove some comments.

Comment: @MikeNaylor still a NO go. Any ideas??

Comment: Alright.  The host may not allow traffic from another subnet. Try to create a NAT rule that translates traffic pointed at the x1 interface for those services as having a source of the x5 interface IP.  Then create a second rule to translate traffic to the x5 interface IP on those services as having a source of the x1 interface IP.  Then on the x1 interface side put the destination as the x1 interface IP instead of the host's.

Comment: @MikeNaylor Can you clarify this? Like I mentioned, i'm not experienced with Sonicwall. The server in X5 is now connected to the internet and can also ping X1 hosts. Now i'm just trying X1 to be able to connect to the server in X5.

Comment: Can you post the two routing rules you have for x1 to x5 and x5 to x1 so I can see? just to make sure we're on the same page?  And did you setup the NAT rule for traffic from x1 to the host on x5 as well?

Comment: @MikeNaylor added the screenshot to the Q! Note that there is no option for X1 subnet when choosing destination or source in the settings for the routing table.

Comment: Ok, I think I see where this got confused.  I got crossed up thinking x1 was a LAN and it is a WAN.  My mistake.  You can remove the two rules (1 and 2) and just add the NAT policy for the external traffic to get to the host.  The routing policies would have applied if it was between LAN interfaces.  Sorry for the confusion.  Also is the LAN traffic from *x0* to x5 working?  Trying to answer between working on stuff...

Comment: @MikeNaylor My mistake as well.. I've mistaken X1 as LAN, when it is indeed WAN. Like i said i can resolve hosts and ping the outside from X5, though access to X5 from LAN (X0) is not working. Can you please clarify on how to add the NAT rule (or is it just below)

Comment: You'd still use the NAT rule as listed below for the WAN x1 to the LAN x5.  Then you'd need to setup the routing rule listed below, which I updated, from x0 to the x5 host.

Comment: An luck getting this to work?

Comment: @MikeNaylor looks like all is working well! Thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Sonicwall Enhanced OS you can define Address Objects and Service objects to make management much simpler.  First, make sure your host or server is listed as an Address Object under Network -> Address Objects.  Then move on to Network -> Services to add your services you wish to route.  Note that you can add individual services and put them into groups.  This makes it simpler to route items based on individual ports or port groups.

Once your Address Object and Services are ready, go to the Firewall->Access Rules and make sure you Allow the service(s) you wish to route from the WAN to LAN zones.  Now that you've allowed the traffic you can go to Network -> NAT policies and click Add at the top.  Here you will use the Address Object and Service/Service group that you created.

[image: Sample NAT Policy]

Above you see that the source is ANY allowing all external IPs, the Translated Source keeps the original information, the Original destination is your WAN IP of your WAN interface, the Translated Destination is your target host, and the Original Service is the ports you wish to map to that target server.  You can translate the services if you like, for instance routing port 3390 to 3389 for RDP on a machine to avoid registry hacks but ensure you have a reverse rule enabled for the outbound path.  You can also define which interfaces this policy is bound to if you like, so for your example the Inbound would be x1 and Outbound x5.

This should allow you to point to your external IP for these services via x.x.x.x:port and route to the target server.

EDIT:

For the internal routing under Network-->Zones choose LAN and check the box for Allow Interface Trust. This should allow traffic to flow between interfaces. Keep in mind this does open all LAN interfaces to share traffic so any segmentation that is currently configured may be broken. If you do not wish for all traffic to be trusted between interfaces then do not use this option.

For specific LAN routing you can manually add a route from x5 subnet to x0 subnet over any service with the local gateway (0.0.0.0) and use the x0 interface.  If you wish to route directly to an individual host then select it as your Destination instead of the x5 Subnet.  Make sure that there is a converse rule to allow traffic from that host to the x0 subnet as well.